# ROS Answers SE migration: gazebo menu

Tags: ros, gazebo, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, ROS Community!

My question looks like foolishly, but there are no any similar questions in ROS answers...

I can't find the application menu in Gazebo. [Here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_b&tut=guided_b2) in "The Menu" section, it illustrated how menu should be to look in general cases, but it isn't like that in my case

The screenshot : [image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226006/gazebo-menu/) by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2016-02-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The menu headings will appear if you mouse over the bar at the very top of the screen that has Gazebo at the far left.

The screen shot you linked to  shows Gazebo when it is set to full screen.

This is an ubuntu thing rather than a ROS thing.

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on 2016-02-08**:
Yes, I got it )) Thank you for reply

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2016-02-12**:
I had the exact same problem when I started with ROS because I was also new to Ubuntu.